# SortedDictionary projection using linq

Tags: linq, lambda, sorteddictionary

I have a `SortedDictionary<double, List<int>>`, I'm trying to iterate through it and grab every 5th element but I want to accumulate the other 4 elements' List members. Is it possible using LINQ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example would help us understand what you want to do.

Comment: And in what kind of structure do you want to store the output? _Is it possible using LINQ?_ Probably with an `Aggregate`, but why strain yourself? This is a routine job with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that this is possible. Its just that it is a repeated question.

I just check that if you want to accumulate using LINQ then you can check the following question:

- [Accumulation of subsequences of a sequence using C#/Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100079/accumulation-of-subsequences-of-a-sequence-using-c-linq).