# Is there a standard LINQ operator that will transform an IEnumerable<T> into another by looking ahead at its own elements

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a standard linq operator that will help me generate, say, an arithmetic progression out of an `IEnumerable<int>` without actually iterating over the elements myself?

For e.g.

```
int[] numbers = { 7, 12, 14, 8 };

// I would like an IEnumerable<int>
// whose values are:
IEnumerable<int> result = ... // { 19, 33, 41 }
```

I want to do this in a single query lazily, i.e. without having to write a `foreach` loop.

I am looking but can't find any combinator out of the standard ones.

I suspect I can use one of the overloads of `Select` coupled with `Aggregate` might help me do that but I am still trying it out myself and am not sure. I thought it'll be interesting to post this question and have someone else race me to it?

**Update**
I have changed my question. The output I thought I wanted was:

```
{ 7 ,19, 33, 41}
```

Jacob answered it correctly with the code:

```
var accumulator = 0;
return numbers.Select(n => accumulator += n);
```

But I am thinking, if I wanted the output to be just

```
{ 19, 33, 41 }
```

How would I "look ahead" into the same source enumerable?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: I just updated the question to include an example output I desire.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9100160/2290059

Comment: No, that guy composes the `runningTotals` destination enumerable himself. That's what I was wondering if I could avoid. It appears as though there is none. Food for thought for anyone wanting to write LINQ operator extensions. MoreLinq, for instance?

Comment: For your second request, just add a .Skip(1) after the select. return numbers.Select(n => accumulator += n).Skip(1);

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey: Thank you. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is usually called scan. There's no built-in operator (although F# defines it as [`Seq.scan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340364.aspx) but you can define it yourself:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TAcc> Scan<T, TAcc>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<TAcc, T, TAcc> f, TAcc initial)
    {
        TAcc current = initial;
        yield return current;
        foreach(T item in seq)
        {
            current = f(current, item);
            yield return current;
        }
    }
```

Scan usually yields the initial value which you don't need so you can `Skip` it:

```
int[] numbers = { 7, 12, 14, 8 };
var result = numbers.Scan((acc, x) => acc + y, 0).Skip(1);
```

Comment: Thank you. So, there isn't in C#. I am now thinking if I could implement it in as a deferred, *streaming* operator.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - What do you mean by 'streaming operator'? If you mean observable sequences then Rx defines [`Observable.Scan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212007.aspx)

Comment: By streaming, I meant that it not go through the sequence in the operator while query construction -- like the `Where` operator but it instead return something like a `ScanIterator` that will run when its `GetEnumerator` is called by the client. I was wondering if I could restrict myself to just Linq to Objects and not impose that the sequence be an `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - This does return a lazy sequence, no work is done until the result is enumerated.

Comment: This functionalisty is available on MoreLinq: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Scan.cs

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built-in operator to do exactly this, but it's fairly easy to implement just through a regular `Select`:

```
var accumulator = 0;
return numbers.Select(n => accumulator += n);
```

Comment: Damn it! Thank you. :-)

Comment: Ok, now I am wondering if I didn't want the first element in the destination to be the same as the first one in the source. So, if I wanted the output to be just `{ 19, 33, 41 }`, I'd really have to look ahead. That's something I am wondering how to do with just a single query.

Comment: You actually answered my original question but I have now updated the question to make it a little more precise with regard to what I had in mind initially.

Comment: I wish I could mark this answer also as the right one.